# window.open() only works with input type but not on tags?

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I'm trying to use window.open() to open a new window with  tag but it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to programming so i get stuck a lot and this one especially doesn't let me find a solution. could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
javascript
var grid2Btn = document.getElementsByClassName('grid2__btn__container');
grid2Btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.open('https://www.google.com/','google', 'top=100,left=100,width=300,height=400');
})

html
<button class="grid2__btn__container">
          <span><img class="magnifier" src="au-logos/search.png" alt="magnifier">click here<span class="new__window__logo"></span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` will return an Array. So in order tor add event listener to them you need to iterate over them with .forEach() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` returns collection of elements.

You can know it:

- by checking the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)
- by checking its real output

  ```js
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid2__btn__container');
  console.log(elements);
  ```
- reading the method name: get**Elements**ByClassName().

So, simply take the first array element of the result and then add an event listener to it.

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('grid2__btn__container');

// Take the first element
const grid2Btn = elements[0];

grid2Btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('Button clicked');
    window.open('https://www.google.com/','google', 'top=100,left=100,width=300,height=400');
});
```

```html
<button class="grid2__btn__container">
          <span><img class="magnifier" src="au-logos/search.png" alt="magnifier">click here<span class="new__window__logo"></span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: it worked after selecting the first element by adding "const grid2Btn = elements[0];" ! Thank you so much!!!